# Inverse of cumsum in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia

The matrix `Y` is defined as

```
Y = cumsum(cumsum(X,dims=1), dims=2)
```

For example,

```
julia> X = [1 4 2 3; 2 4 5 2; 4 3 4 1; 2 5 4 2];
julia> Y = cumsum(cumsum(X,dims=1), dims=2)
4x4 Matrix{Int64}:
1  5  7 10
3 11 18 23
7 18 29 35
9 25 40 48
```

I want to reproduce the matrix `X` from `Y`. It seems that function `diff` is helpful. However, as you can see below, we cannot reproduce the first line and first column of `X`.

```
julia> diff(diff(y, dims=1), dims=2)
3x3 Matrix{Int64}:
4 5 2
3 4 1
5 4 2
```

So, I concatenate zeros. Then, it works.

```
julia> y00 = vcat(zeros(5)',hcat(zeros(4), y))
5x5 Matrix{Int64}:
0  0  0  0  0
0  1  5  7 10
0  3 11 18 23
0  7 18 29 35
0  9 25 40 48

julia> diff(diff(y00, dims=1), dims=2)
4x4 Matrix{Int64}:
1  5  7 10
3 11 18 23
7 18 29 35
9 25 40 48
```

But I think concatenating takes time and memory.
Is there any better idea to reproduce `X` from `Y`?

**Context**

I want to expand the above matrices `X` and `Y` to any dimensional array. For example, I want to reconstruct a three-dimensional array `X` from given three-dimensional array

```
Y = cumsum( cumsum( cumsum(X, dims=1), dims=2), dims=3)
```

Comment: I was looking for better code in terms of efficiency, and the post has some constructive answers that improve the speed. Commonly, concatenating is not a good choice for larger arrays since it takes memory, and this question is natural. I do not understand why you need to close this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When both speed and succinctness are required, it's hard to beat powerful Julia packages like [Tullio.jl](https://github.com/mcabbott/Tullio.jl). Here is a one-liner that's about 4X faster than the fastest solution by @DanGetz.

```
using Tullio
cumdiff(Y) = @tullio X[i,j] = Y[i,j] - Y[i,j-1] - Y[i-1,j] + Y[i-1,j-1]
```

Benchmarking with a 100-by-100 matrix gives:

```
X = rand(0:100,100,100)
Y = cumsum(cumsum(X,dims=1), dims=2)
@btime cumdiff($Y)
@btime decumsum3($Y)
  4.957 μs (17 allocations: 464 bytes)
  21.300 μs (2 allocations: 78.17 KiB)
```

**Fix:** The code above was using the predefined `X` instead of creating a new one. This is fixed below, and the speedup is more like 3.5X and not 4X.

```
function cumdiff(Y)
    X = similar(Y)
    X[1] = Y[1]
    for i = 2:size(Y,1) X[i,1] = Y[i,1] - Y[i-1,1] end
    for j = 2:size(Y,2) X[1,j] = Y[1,j] - Y[1,j-1] end
    @tullio X[i,j] = Y[i,j] - Y[i,j-1] - Y[i-1,j] + Y[i-1,j-1]
end
```

```
@btime cumdiff($Y)
@btime decumsum3($Y)
  6.000 μs (4 allocations: 78.23 KiB)
  21.300 μs (2 allocations: 78.17 KiB)
```

Comment: Something is up. How come `cumdiff` doesn't even allocate enough for the return matrix?

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I wanted the version for any array dimension. I mean, I want to reconstruct `X` from `Y = cumsum( cumsum( cumsum(X, dims=1), dims=2), dims=3)`.
Is it possible to generalize `cumdiff(Y)` for the general array dimension?

Comment: Maybe this should be called `cumdiff!(X, Y)`. To make a new array, it would be `@tullio Xnew[i,j] := ` instead. There isn't a straightforward way to write it for N dimensions, although if you only in fact need 3 or 4 you can write them out, `if ndims(Y)==1; @tullio X[i] := ...; elseif ndims(Y)==2; @tullio X[i,j] := ...; elseif` etc.

Comment: Thanks @mcabbott, yes I fixed that above.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't see these numbers on my machine. I get something like `6.400 μs (4 allocations: 78.23 KiB), 13.500 μs (2 allocations: 78.17 KiB)` for my fixed version vs. your `decumsum5`. That's still 2X, am I missing something?

Comment: Having benchmarked on my computer, I see a  speedup only on larger matrices. In fact `decumsum5` is faster than `cumdiff` on 20x20. Also, it would be better to take the non-allocating version (to keep only the working stuff). [I think the difference in our benchmarks is the sizes. on 100x100 `cumdiff` is faster - Tullio indeed is an impressive package]

Comment: Thanks @mcabbott. I agree we need the Inclusion-exclusion principle to extend `cumdiff(Y)` for any dimensional array, and it takes time. 

It seems `cumdiff(Y)` is the best way for matrices, and `decumsum(Y; dims)` is best for any dimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

See EDIT section below.

Some options so far:

```
decumsum1(X) = begin
    Z = copy(X)
    Z[2:end,:] .-= Z[1:end-1,:]
    Z[:,2:end] .-= Z[:,1:end-1]
    return Z
end

decumsum2(X) = begin   # This is from question #
    r,c = size(X)
    Z = vcat(zeros(eltype(X),r+1)',
          hcat(zeros(eltype(X),c), X))
    return diff(diff(Z, dims=1), dims=2)
end

decumsum3(Y) = [Y[I]-(I[2]==1 ? 0 : Y[I[1],I[2]-1])-
  (I[1]==1 ? 0 : Y[I[1]-1,I[2]])+
  ((I[1]==1 || I[2]==1) ? 0 : Y[I[1]-1,I[2]-1]) 
  for I in CartesianIndices(Y)]

function decumsum5(Y) 
    R = similar(Y)
    h,w = size(Y)
    R[1,1] = Y[1,1]
    @inbounds for i=2:h R[i,1] = Y[i,1]-Y[i-1,1] ; end
    @inbounds for j=2:w R[1,j] = Y[1,j]-Y[1,j-1] ; end
    @inbounds for i=2:h,j=2:w R[i,j] = Y[i,j]-Y[i-1,j]-Y[i,j-1]+Y[i-1,j-1] ; end
    return R
end
```

Giving the following benchmarks:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> decumsum1(Y) == decumsum2(Y) == decumsum3(Y) == X
true
julia> @btime decumsum1($Y);
  352.571 ns (5 allocations: 832 bytes)

julia> @btime decumsum2($Y);
  475.438 ns (9 allocations: 1.14 KiB)

julia> @btime decumsum3($Y);
  96.875 ns (1 allocation: 192 bytes)

julia> @btime decumsum5($Y);
  60.805 ns (1 allocation: 192 bytes)
```

EDIT: Perhaps the prettier solutions is:

```
decumsum(Y; dims) = [Y[I] - ( 
    I[dims]==1 ? 0 : Y[(ifelse(k == dims,I[k]-1,I[k]) 
      for k in 1:ndims(Y))...]
  ) for I in CartesianIndices(Y)]
```

and with it, the `cumsum` can be walked back:

```
julia> decumsum(decumsum(Y, dims=1), dims=2)
4×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  4  2  3
 2  4  5  2
 4  3  4  1
 2  5  4  2

julia> decumsum(decumsum(Y, dims=1), dims=2) == X
true

julia> @btime decumsum(decumsum($Y, dims=1), dims=2);
  165.656 ns (2 allocations: 384 bytes)
```

with nice performance and also generalized to any Array dimension.

Update: another version `decumsum5` added. Still faster.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I wanted the version for any array dimension, so decumsum is quite helpful for me.